# Prizes for App Showdown winners

Tags: application-development

I'm the winner of App Showdown community vote. I'm just curious about the question: when the prizes will be presented? I found no information about it.

Comment: BTW, what about t-shirts for everyone?

Comment: I don't find the fact of not contacting you strange. The whole contest was bad organized ( the least bad thing you can say ;) ). Congratulations on your win, despite the fact that the Community Vote did not show the really valuable apps.

Comment: @mivoligo I received a message about t-shirts and filled suggested form with mail address. It was in august (deadline for filling the form was 4th of September).

Comment: @Riateche I did that too and was expecting nice surprise from the postman. Well, we have to wait longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll send you the prizes very soon, with a tracking code so that you can track when they get to you.

I apologize for the delay, which I've been responsible for, but I'll make sure they get to you asap.

Comment: any news about t-shirts? I was hoping to celebrate 12.10 wearing Ubuntu t-shirt but haven't receive it yet. :( I know you're guys busy and limited in number, but keeping us waiting without communication can't be a good thing. Sorry I'm saying this, but nothing hurts as broken promise. :(

Comment: I'm also still waiting for my t-shirt and I am a bit disappointed about the promise that was not hold until now. I really hope canonical is able to hold it's promises and send those 130 t-shirts to the participants soon.